# SICK LMS500 connection and drivers

Tags: ros, lidar, sicklms, sicktoolbox-wrapper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.

I would like to ask the ROS community, if anyone had any success on compiling a node or wrapper for the SICK LMS500 Lidar scanner. I have already examined the sicktoolbox and the links from adept robotics and github but still I can't receive any data from the scanner. Apparently the problem occurs because the LMS200 and LMS500 use different connection interfaces, RS232 & Ethernet respectively. Does anyone have any thoughts or experience to share regarding this scanner?
My Os is Ubuntu 12.04 and my distro is Fuerte.

Thank you all in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56416/sick-lms500-connection-and-drivers/) by [dkc](https://answers.ros.org/users/4307/dkc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-02-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TimElery](https://answers.ros.org/users/1824/timelery/) on 2014-01-23**:
Do you happen to have the Sick USB driver for the LMS5xx that comes on the CD with the scanner. We need it. Thanks.

**Comment by [romi](https://answers.ros.org/users/34891/romi/) on 2018-05-02**:
did you get the problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're currently using [this repo fork](https://github.com/rhuitl/laser_drivers) (also on [our github](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/laser_drivers)) to connect to an LMS511. Didn't need to do any kind of reconfiguration in the node or LIDAR aside from changing the IP of the LIDAR in the sicklms5xx.cpp file.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2013-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dkc](https://answers.ros.org/users/4307/dkc/) on 2013-03-19**:
Thank you Ryan for the quick reply. I just wanted to ask if you connect the scanner directly to your PC with the Ethernet cable or via a switch. I have an error "ERROR: I/O Exception - SickLMS5xx::_setupConnection: socket error on connect()!" and I would appreciate your thoughts about this.

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2013-03-19**:
We usually use a switch, but I recall a direct connection works as well. You'll just need to make sure your PC IP is on the same subnet as the LIDAR. Also, the LIDAR *may* be set to DHCP by default. We work with so many LIDARs, I can't remember off hand (use SOPAS to reconfigure if it is).

**Comment by [TimElery](https://answers.ros.org/users/1824/timelery/) on 2014-01-23**:
Do you happen to have the USB driver for the LMS5xx. We need it.

Thanks.

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2014-01-24**:
For others who might be interested in how Tim & I solved his problem offline, you don't in fact need the USB driver. However, if you're building your own cable, you should wire it as per the pinout in the manual (https://mysick.com/saqqara/im0037514.pdf), not as a crossover.

**Comment by [TimElery](https://answers.ros.org/users/1824/timelery/) on 2014-01-24**:
Thanks again Ryan!

**Comment by [张京林](https://answers.ros.org/users/19842/%E5%BC%A0%E4%BA%AC%E6%9E%97/) on 2016-02-23**:
@TimElery Hi, Tim, maybe you need this:[Type:   USB driver
Name: USB driver
Version:   2.06.02
Software category:   Driver
Size: 1.13 MB
Language: English
Product family   LMS5xx](https://www.sick.com/de/en/downloads/eula?code=swp398445)

**Comment by [Aakash](https://answers.ros.org/users/28734/aakash/) on 2016-12-07**:
@ryan i get this error when i run the launch file
ERROR: I/O exception - SickLMS5xx::_setupConnection: socket error on connect()!
[ERROR] [1481123036.354943702]: Initialize failed!
And also I'm connected over Ethernet...

Please help!